# How do deploy nodejs angular2 application in cloudfoundry

Tags: node.js, angular, cloud-foundry

Source code can be found here

```
https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git
```

Seems like cloudfoundry can't determine the health of my nodejs application

The way I use to push this application:

```
cf push node-hj
```

here are cloudfoundry logs

[image]

I tried to push this application with flowing:

```
cf push node-hj -c "node start"
```

Same error as above

Comment: what is the error you're getting, what does the log say, how do your config, manifest files etc. look like?

Answer (score 0):

You are likely facing the issue mentioned on https://github.com/angular/quickstart/issues/215

At least it is the one I can see after:

```
$ cf dev start
$ git clone https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git .
$ cf push test
$ cf logs test --recent
[skipped]
2017-03-02T19:05:17.67+0800 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]OUT > angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart /home/vcap/app
2017-03-02T19:05:17.67+0800 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]OUT > npm run build
2017-03-02T19:05:18.09+0800 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]OUT > angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build /home/vcap/app
2017-03-02T19:05:18.09+0800 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]OUT > tsc -p src/
2017-03-02T19:05:18.09+0800 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR sh: 1: tsc: not found
```